# Возможна ли генерация случайных символов в java?

Tags: java

Именно генерация символов, а НЕ цифр.

Comment: а чем символы особо отличаются от Цифр?

Цифра тот же символ, если быть точным, любая буква, цифра, точка, запятая - это СИМВОЛ или набор символов(кодов)!

Comment: Поскольку между символами и натуральными числами можно установить взаимно однозначное соответствие, то генерация случайных последовательностей символов эквивалентна оной для чисел.

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись, уже всё реализовала)

Comment: 2 автор: этот код выдает ужасные результы,вам лучше не смотреть.:  

    int a = (int) 'a';
    System.out.println(a);
    char b = (char) (a + 1);
    System.out.println(b);

p.s. думаю как сгенерировать число разберетесь сами

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, какие собственно говоря проблемы то? Навскидку назову 2 способа:

1. Нумеруем массив возможных значений символов char[0],...,char[N], далее случайно генерируем индексы массива от 0 до N - в итоге получим массив `char` из которых составляем собственно строку.
2. Генерируем случайную последовательность `long` - конвертируем в строку. Далее строку пропускаем через хэш функцию SHA-1 или MD5